# Load a select input field with collection data in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor. I am using `Meteor-x-editable-bootstrap` to create a dropdown, the options of which have to be populated with data from a Mongo collection.

Right now, my code is:

```
$('#options').editable({
  type: 'select',
  source: [
    {text: 'Option 1'},
    {text: 'Option 2'},
    {text: 'Option 3'}
  ]
});
```

Those are hardcoded values ('Option 1', 'Option 2' etc). Now, I have a collection `Options` in which there is a field `Values`. How do I set the `source` array dynamically to retrieve data from the collection? Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

The meteor pattern for a menu doesn't require jQuery at all. In your template you just iterate over the collection to create the menu:

```
<template name="myMenu">
  <select #id="mySelect>
    {{#each item}}
      <option value={{_id}}>{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

Then you just need to have a helper that returns the items you need:

```
Template.myMenu.helpers({
  items() {
    return MyCollection.find();
  }
});
```

And an event handler:

```
Template.myMenu.events({
  'onChange #mySelect'(ev) {
    ...handle the event.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the same code you have written every-time you retrieve the data?

```
var receivedJson = getNewOptions(); // your data retrieving code here
$('#options').editable({
  type: 'select',
  source: receivedJson
});
```